# How can I determine if a Sequence exist in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to create a SQL script to determine if a sequence exists in a SQL Server 2012 database. I am familiar with process for determine if a stored procedure exist but not sequence. Thank you.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The script to determine whether or not a Sequence exists in SQL Server 2012 is very similar to checking for Stored Procedures. Consider the following code that checks to see if a Stored Procedure exists:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.objects
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SProc_Name]') AND type IN (N'P', N'PC')
```

The values of 'P' and 'PC' for the type specify the type of the sys.object is a SQL Stored Procedure or a Assembly (CLR) stored-procedure. To check for a sequence, you just need to change it to 'SO' which indicates it is a Sequence Object:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.objects
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Sequence_Name]') AND type = 'SO'
```

For example, if you want to create a Sequence if it doesn't exist, you could use the following code:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Sequence_Name]') AND type = 'SO')
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[Sequence_Name] 
    AS [bigint]
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
    CACHE  3 
GO
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: As of SQL Server 2005, it's preferable to use the **more focused** catalog views, like `sys.sequences` rather than querying the "catch-all" `sys.objects` and having to remember the necessary `type` for your object in question ....

Comment: @marc_s is correct that it's easier to remember the "more focused catalog views." Out of habit, I still use [sys.objects type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 "link to full list of types"), but I am now considering making the transition.

Comment: @StevenFerrer Based on the article you provided, "Approach 4" indicates that "`sys.sysobjects`...will be deprecated" and not `sys.objects`: "Microsoft is suggesting to use the catalog view `sys.objects` instead of `sys.sysobjects` system..."

Comment: @myidealab, good catch! I've deleted my comment since it doesn't really add value to this answer. haha. thanks very much!

Answer (score 13):

By checking data in [sys.sequences](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff877934.aspx) table:

```
select *
from sys.sequences
where object_id = object_id('schema_name.sequence_name')
```

actually that if you're sure that there's no object other than sequence with name equals `'schema_name.sequence_name'`, you could just check `object_id('schema_name.sequence_name') is not null`

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/37e7c/4)</kbd>**

Answer (score 10):

This is another shortcut version of Tim S:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('schema_name.sequence_name', 'SO') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    DROP SEQUENCE schema_name.sequence_name
END
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.  This will list all of the sequences for a given database.

```
SELECT
seq.name AS [Sequence Name],
seq.object_id AS [Object ID],
seq.create_date AS [Creation Date],
seq.modify_date AS [Last Modified Date],
SCHEMA_NAME(seq.schema_id) AS [Schema],
CAST(seq.precision AS int) AS [Numeric Precision],
CAST(seq.scale AS int) AS [Numeric Scale],
ISNULL(seq.start_value,N'''') AS [Start Value],
ISNULL(seq.increment,N'''') AS [Increment Value],
ISNULL(seq.minimum_value,N'''') AS [Min Value],
ISNULL(seq.maximum_value,N'''') AS [Max Value],
CAST(seq.is_cycling AS bit) AS [Is Cycle Enabled],
ISNULL(seq.cache_size,0) AS [Cache Size],
ISNULL(seq.current_value,N'''') AS [Current Value]
FROM sys.sequences AS seq
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using SQL Server 17.4 (Latest version of MS SQL Sever) and this SQL script worked with me.
This SQL script, for example, creates the sequence if not exists.

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT [name]
FROM sys.sequences
WHERE [name] = 'seq_businessTripRequest'
)
BEGIN

CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[seq_businessTripRequest]
AS [BIGINT]
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
MINVALUE-9223372036854775808
MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
CACHE;

END;
```